Avalanche effect on React re-renders due to Context API
I know this is an over-asked question, but I have a specific problem with Context and, actually, the React rendering mechanism.
I'll be quick:

I have a sort of canvas where I add and remove React components.
These React components are added, removed, and updated inside a global JS object (canvas)
The canvas is actually a tree with different layers: a column, a row, a component, a subcomponent...
There is a history of changes (copies of the canvas stacked into an array)

Undos and redos substitute the copy of the canvas

changes are pushed to the history as a new canvas version



I use a Global Context that wraps everything.

I have tried splitting the context in different parts

I have tried getting rid of the context

The problem is always the push to the history




So far, I have tried the following solution: Every component changes by itself, only updating the single part of the canvas that is actually changed. I was using Immer to do this. Everything fine, re-rendering of components was triggered due to change of state in the component itself, without triggering other re-renders (no other component shared state).As soon as I got to the history feature, I met my fate: Pushing the state to the history requires a change of state for the history, that has to be shared.

The history is basically a global component

Every change has to be notified to the history, so the history has to change and has to be shared amongst components.

I can accept that undos and redos trigger re-renders for the entire page.


So, the main issue here is that I still have to notify a change of state to the history which is shared. Even if the history would be just a copy of every single component, and stored in the single component, what happens if I delete a component? I still need to push to the history.
I mean, you can see I'm lost here.
I found a temporary workaround that I had to delete from my project: Intersection Observers. The problem with those was that user experience was drastically impacted by unpredictable behaviors during scrolling. But, it was working fine.
Right now, I have left my app as a re-render machine, that re-renders at every single damn change.Even if I do the slightest change, the state changes in the context (in the history) and it triggers changes.
I even tried a pub/sub approach, where components would subscribe to changes in the history, but we're still there, the history is shared and has to change at every change.What's the best thing I can do here? My best bet so far is that I get Intersection Observers to work so damn good that I don't need to worry about re-rendering because everything is limited to what I see in the page.
Unless I do create a sophisticated history that only contains sort of OP codes, like (UNDO_ADD_COMPONENT => {// Reverse logic of ADD_COMPONENT}
But still... I have to push this to the history ahahah
And it would also require me to refactor the entire codebase, which is not small at all right now and is going to increase.
Any suggestions?
Thanks!

Hello! Welcome to stack overflow, I'd suggest you check out How to ask specifically the segment regarding MREs. Without code to debug or the ability to reproduce your issue, it is hard to offer advice. If you edit your question to include MRE I would be happy to help further!
